# Digit validation not work properly in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, validation

created simple script to allow only digit value as argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":A:" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        A)
            if [[ $OPTARG != *[[:digit:]]* ]]                                     
            then                                                                  
                printf "Invalid argument\n"                                    
            else
                printf "Valid argument %s\n" $OPTARG                                     
            fi
            ;;  
        ?)
            return
            ;;

    esac

done
```

then executed it by different option and got unexpected output.

```
$ ./test.bash -A 1
Valid argument 1 

$ ./test.bash -A a
Invalid argument

$ ./test.bash -A 1,2,3
Valid argument 1,2,3

$ ./test.bash -A  A12B
Valid argument A12B


$ ./test.bash -A  12AB
Valid argument 12AB
```

So from above output i can't distinguished only digit value allow as argument. 
Have any idea how to allow only digit value?

Comment: Why did you surround `[[:digit:]]` in stars? I think that is the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a valid OPTARG can have any number of digits, two approaches come to mind.  First, you can check OPTARG for the presence of any non-digit:

```
if [[ $OPTARG == *[^[:digit:]]* ]]
```

Or, second, you can use regular expressions and require that OPTARG not (`!`) be all digits (`[:digit:]]+`) from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`):

```
if [[ ! $OPTARG =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
```

Comment: Thanks john for your timely help.